# How to truncate 'back' button for headerTitle in react-navigation?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation with `StackNavigator`. Is there a way to avoid the overlapping of the back button label and the `headerTitle` by truncating the back button label?

```
const MainNavigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.CiPrimary
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        height: 50,
        width: 140
    },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerTitle:
    <Text>LONG TEXT FOR TESTING</Text>
}
```

Illustration of issue:

[image: Overlapping of back button and header title]

Answer (score 1):

(This Answer takes into account that the viewer is using react-navigation 5.x)

> In Your Screen component

```js
export const screenOptions = (navData) => {
  let title = navData.route.params.movieTitle;
  if (title.length > 18) {
    title = title.substr(0, 18) + "...";
  }
  return {
    headerTitle: title,
  };
};
```

Here, since we are using substr() , you can use it accordingly and truncate it to custom match your case, keeping in mind the edge cases.

> Then you can import it in your AppNavigator.js or wherever you initialize your navigator (in my case below ;)

```js
import {screenOptions as MoviesDetailScreenOptions} from
"../screens/MovieDetailScreen";
```

> > Here screenOptions is the named-export you are using MoviesDetailScreenOptions is the alias if i am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Create a style for your button label because it now left for you to style it your self and you can style it any way you want.

```
         const styles = {
             leftTouch: { 
               flexDirection: 'row',
               ...
             },
             customStyle: { 
               paddingLeft: 10,
               ...
             }
             textStyle: {
             width: 60,
             fontSize: 14,
             ...... 
             }
         }
         const { leftTouch, customStyle, textStyle} = styles;
```

Instead of Icon you can use `<Image />` but am assuming you are using an icon i.e react-native-vector-icon or likes.

**N.B** Now you have control of everything the button should do especially when pressed.

```
         const MainNavigationOptions = {
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: colors.CiPrimary
                },
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    color: 'white',
                    height: 50,
                    width: 140
                },
             .....
               headerLeft: ( <TouchableOpacity style={leftTouch} onPress={() => goBack()} >
                               <Icon name="ios-arrow-dropleft-circle-outline" size={25} style={customStyle} color="#ffffff" />
                               <Text numberOfLines={1} style={textStyle}>A Longer Text for testing</Text>
                             </TouchableOpacity>
                           )   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to shorten the back button label, why not use either:

- `headerBackTitle` (change the Back label for the previous screen, put it in navigationOptions of the previous screen);
- `headerBackTitleStyle` (change the Back label displayed on current screen, put it in navigationOptions of the current screen)